# Use Liouville-Ostrowsi theorem

Tags: differential-algebra

I don't know how to answer this questions :
1) $e^x/x, exp(exp(x))$ as no elementary primitive.
2) $1/(1+x^2)$ as no elementary primitive in $R(x)$ but have one in $C(x)$.
If someone could help me i will be happy :D.
Thanks !

Comment: Page 6 and page 10 [here](http://msp.org/pjm/1968/24-1/pjm-v24-n1-p16-p.pdf) have a statement of the theorem and an example of how it is applied.

Comment: OK so basically i must show that the verify a differential equation wich has no solution right ?

Comment: cause i don't know how to do with $exp(exp(x))$ since $exp(x)$ is not in $C(X)$.